What is photon direction of backward ASE (amplified spontaneous emission)?
While "laser causes excitation" is natural, CPT symmetry requires also "laser causes deexcitation" scenario, both used e.g. in STED microscopes through diode lasers.
In common optical amplifiers one of these causalities (backward ASE) is removed by optical isolator placed in forward position.
I have a few interesting applications for backward ASE (e.g. https://www.qaif.org/2wqc ), so my question is if we could separate it e.g. analogously: could we leave only backward ASE by placing optical isolator in reversed direction?.
In other words: what is photon direction of backward ASE?
Is this photon direction tested in literature? (wasn't able to find)
If not, it could be checked e.g. as below ( https://arxiv.org/pdf/2409.15399 ): reverse optical isolator to backward position and monitor population level of excited target e.g. testing its spontaneous emission, looking at response delay. Maybe somebody here has equipment to test it?


ASE is not because of CPT: you see ASE in every direction, the reason why you see more ASE in pumping direction is because there is more gain towards that direction, not because of CPT. CPT would mean that in the produced light has the same photon energy, which is not the case in ASE, where photons are of the fluorescence energy.

I emphasize: ASE goes in every direction! Depending on your gain geometry you will see more or less ASE: for example on a thin-disk, ASE is mainly perpendicular to laser pumping/laser emission. Why? well, because the perpendicular direction usually has a path length seeing gain which is 100s of times longer than the path length along the pumping direction.

Physics is believed to be CPT symmetric, what requires existence of CPT analog of "laser causes excitation": "lasers causes deexcitation" with reversed photon trajectory - as e.g. in below setting. Do you have a different interpretation of its laser amplifying deexcitation from upper EDF toward laser?

Well, 1: just saying "laser causes excitation" as the basis for your CPT, then don't look at light amplification through stimulated emission, but at the single process of exciting an atom: rabbi cycling. 2: the CPT symmetric process is obvious: take the low laser level photon + the phonon and get the pump photon. Alternatively, look into nonlinear parametric processes like SHG and its back conversion.

Also, because in your experimental example, the laser only causes excitation, both forward and backward: you take a laser, pump an active fiber, and see output at both sides, ie without seed you see ASE in both directions, as a clear indication of a single direction of the CPT symmetry, ie it does not at all show the reversed process, only energy conversion from laser pump photons into lower energy photons of the ASE and heated fiber.

Indeed Rabi cycle is analogous to coupled oscillators: exchanging energy in both directions, the same from CPT perspective - using periodically "laser causes excitation/deexcitation" with reversed photon directions (switching in CPT perspective). The latter is in agreement e.g. with backward ASE in diagram below: laser causes target deexcitation with photons traveling toward laser.

Ok, last try. Your questions's initial statement: STED microscopy = laser de excitation, yes, CPT symmetry. All these ASE stuff: just plain old laser causes excitation, no switched CPT analog. I have an exercise: if indeed your system shows the switched CPT perspective, please elucidate me, if I switch it back to "normal" direction, I get the normal "laser excites" picture, through the ASE point of view, how does that work?

You are ignoring energy conservation....a big no no

I don't understand? It is satisfied by Rabi cycles, coupled pendula exchanging energy in both directions. Optical isolator blocks energy exchange through optical photons in one direction, transforming this energy probably mainly into heat.

Yes, I agree that Rabi cycling obeys energy conservation. What I am saying is that backwards ASE as a supposed time reversal CPT analog, as you describe, does not work. Photon energies do not add up! STED uses a donut laser of lower photon energy than the excitation one: CPT analog. Backwards ASE: normal laser excitation and normal time arrow

In Rabi cycle exchanging energy in both directions, laser periodically push/pull photons to the target, these two are reversed in CPT perspective. The "pull" seems exactly as in backward ASE in below setting. I don't see a problem with energy conservation - ASE is amplified spontaneous emission, only increases probability of directional release of energy from excited atoms.

Ok, then pretending that indeed this backward ASE is the "reverse" symmetry. Tell me how does the reverse of this reverse looks like? According to you it should look like "laser excites".....

Yes, CPT of "laser causes excitation" is "laser causes deexcitation" with reversed photon trajectory, and applying CPT again you go back to former "laser causes excitation".

Please tackle ASE from thin disks and show me the reverse CPT analog. Your picture should be independent of geometry...

Here (from https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/841259 ) is a clear example of amplified backward ASE photons emitted from excited target (upper EDF) toward laser (left):

So indeed in backward ASE laser causes increased emission from target toward laser - kind of pulling photons.
It can be viewed as "laser causes deexcitation" CPT analog of standard "laser causes excitation" scenario.
